# How to draw resonance structures for CH3COCN

Tags: bond, resonance

What are the resonance structures of $\ce{CH3COCN}$ molecule?

Comment: You mean Pyruvonitrile?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are the significant resonance structures for pyruvonitrile.

[image]

Comment: just curios, how do you draw these structures?

Comment: I use ChemSketch, it's free.

Comment: what is ChemSketch?

Comment: How to show lone pairs electrons of atoms of these structures?

Comment: ChemSketch is a free software package that let's you draw chemical structures.  It's free, so it doesn't do things like show lone pairs very easily, but it can be done in a convoluted sort of way.  http://www.acdlabs.com/resources/freeware/